# How to add session multidimensional array into database and update in real time?

Tags: php, jquery, session, multidimensional-array

My array i.e $_SESSION['cart_array'] contains:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => abc123 [quantity] => 2 [unit_price] => 500 ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => def456 [quantity] => 3 [unit_price] => 100 ) )
```

I am using this code to insert into my database:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item){ $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_added(id,ip_address,order_id,email,item_id,unit_price,quantity,total,pay_status)values('','','','','".$each_item['item_id']."','".$each_item['quantity']."','".$each_item['unit_price']."','','')"); if(!mysql_query( $sql)){
// maybe not the best use of `die` here?
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}echo "record added"; }
```

My problem is when I run the script it add only one item ie:

```
item_id=qwerty,quantity=2 and unit_price=500
```

to the table where as I have two items in the `$_SESSION['cart_array']`. And mysql error shows:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

How to entry two and multiple items into database?

Comment: This question is extremely broad... What php code do you have so far? What have you tried? What libraries are you using? What is your database connection information?

Answer (score 0):

You will need:

- a php script that adds the session array to db
- a jquery code to call the php script via an ajax request to trigger the insertion

PHP:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO sessions_tbl (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'][0] as $key => $val){
  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $key);
  $stmt->bindParam(':value', $val);
  $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

JS:

```
$('ADD-TO-CART-BTN').on('click', function(){
   $.post('http://yourwebsite.com/session-update-script.php', {}, function(response){

   });
});
```

Comment: thank for your response @Sam Battat but i cant execute the code,i tried to do with ur code with my db table name but cant success

Comment: What errors do you get it any when you run the php script from the browser by typing in the script address in your address bar?

Comment: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\sandgrainstudio\php\cart-update.php on line 42......my database table name id product_added and coloum name is item_id,quantity,unit_price....as is in array

Comment: well my code assumed that you have db connection in place and you are using PDO here is what connection you have to make first `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);`